# How to print rdlc report with reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

*hello guys can anyone help me how to print my receipt using a controll button?*

> this is my screen shot [1]" https://ibb.co/kfk8SF
>
> if I click the "SAVE PRINT" button a preview dialog box appeared
> all I want is to automatically print the report that i want by clicking only the button and no dialog box appeared

[2] https://ibb.co/kSpDuv

Answer (score 1):

You can get default printer name first (before opening report viewer):

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings settings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
defaultPrinterName = settings.PrinterName;
```

When printing, assign your printer name to `PrinterName` property of `PrintDocument`:

```
 LocalReport rep = new LocalReport();
 //set your data and parameters here
 //...
 rep.Refresh();
 ExportLandscape(rep);

 PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
 PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
 ps.PrinterName = defaultPrinterName;
 printDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;

 printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
 m_currentPageIndex = 0;
 printDoc.Print();
```

The event to handle actual print:

```
 //this has to declared somewhere at the "top":
 private IList<Stream> m_streams;
 private int m_currentPageIndex;


 private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) {
        Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }
```

Here is code to create print document:

```
private void ExportPortrait(LocalReport report) {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
}

private void ExportLandscape(LocalReport report) {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;
}

private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek) {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
 }
```

You can use something like [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to convert code to vb.net is needed.